# How to disable AutoComplPop completions in comments?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I've recently started using [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879), but I find the popup annoying when I'm writing comments (as I usually don't need autocomplition when writing a comment).

Is there a configuration option or a quick hack that can effectively disable AutoComplPop when the insertion point is in a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question of performance when checking the syntax on every cursor move, I had to implement this myself, and made this into the [OnSyntaxChange](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085) plugin.

With this plugin, setting this up can be done in just three lines (e.g. in .vimrc):

```
call OnSyntaxChange#Install('Comment', '^Comment$', 0, 'i')
autocmd User SyntaxCommentEnterI silent! AcpLock
autocmd User SyntaxCommentLeaveI silent! AcpUnlock
```

For me, the performance impact is noticeable (depending on the filetype and syntax), but tolerable. Try for yourself!

Comment: I used something very similar but with `NeoComplCacheLock` and `NeoComplCacheUnlock` -- thanks for the great plugin!

Comment: how might I achieve the same effect while inside a python docstring (multiline comment)?

Comment: @MattBall: Just find out the name of the syntax group (probably `String`), and use that instead of `Comment'` in the above snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check via a hook into `CursorMovedI` that you're currently in a comment, and can then use AutoComplPop's `:AcpLock` to disable it temporarily. (And undo with `:AcpUnlock` once you move out of comments.)

Detecting comments for various filetypes is best done by querying the syntax highlighting; this way, you benefit from the syntax definitions of existing filetypes.

Here's a snippet for this:

```
function! IsOnSyntaxItem( syntaxItemPattern )
    " Taking the example of comments:
    " Other syntax groups (e.g. Todo) may be embedded in comments. We must thus
    " check whole stack of syntax items at the cursor position for comments.
    " Comments are detected via the translated, effective syntax name. (E.g. in
    " Vimscript, 'vimLineComment' is linked to 'Comment'.)
    for l:id in synstack(line('.'), col('.'))
        let l:actualSyntaxItemName = synIDattr(l:id, 'name')
        let l:effectiveSyntaxItemName = synIDattr(synIDtrans(l:id), 'name')
        if l:actualSyntaxItemName =~# a:syntaxItemPattern || l:effectiveSyntaxItemName =~# a:syntaxItemPattern
            return 1
        endif
    endfor
    return 0
endfunction
```

With this, you should be able to stitch together a solution.

Comment: how does checking for this affect vim performance? does it make it much slower?

Comment: It's okay; see my other answer for a ready-made solution, and try it for yourself.