# Disable Vims autocomplete when writing comments

Tags: vim, vi

How can I disable autocomplete in Vim when writing a comment or docstring? I tried `au FileType * setl fo-=cro` and `set fo-=c fo-=o fo-=r` but that didn't help. I use Neocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085) may help with this.

First, you need to generate events when entering / leaving comments:

```
call OnSyntaxChange#Install('Comment', '^Comment$', 0, 'i')
```

Then, hook commands to enable / disable the auto completion to the events. Fortunately, Neocomplete provides those:

```
autocmd User SyntaxCommentEnterI silent! NeoCompleteLock
autocmd User SyntaxCommentLeaveI silent! NeoCompleteUnlock
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723499/), which does something similar for the *AutoComplPop* plugin.

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer.